# How do I run capybara conditional to the browser?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cucumber, capybara

Synopsis:  I have capybara that executes tests flawlessly in Chrome, but breaks in IE.  I plan to mitigate this by adding additional automation when on IE.

I'm accessing this without rails, so ...

```
request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

has not been available to me.

What is the best way to run script conditional to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have [registered each browser as a driver](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#configuring-and-adding-drivers), you could perform logic based on the current driver:

```
if Capybara.current_driver == :selenium_ie
  # Do IE stuff
else
  # Do Chrome stuff
end
```

(where `:selenium_id` is the name of your registered driver.)

If you have not registered drivers, you could also check the browser's name:

```
if page.driver.browser.browser == :internet_explorer
  # Do IE stuff
else
  # Do Chrome stuff
end
```

The second approach would actually be more clear by checking the options hash:

```
if page.driver.options[:browser] == :internet_explorer
  # Do IE stuff
else
  # Do Chrome stuff
end
```

Comment: The second is perfect! No scoping required.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my polished solution....

```
    def win?
      b = page.driver.browser.browser.to_s
      if b == 'internet_explorer'
        return true
      else
        return false
      end
    end
```